# Button state info

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

The question is similar to "how to pass data from different viewController" but in this case I need another information, I know how to pass the data from one viewController to another but I don't know how to tell to the second viewController a specific state of an object that is in the first view. In my case I have some buttons in the first view that go in.

```
button.isHidden = true
```

after the tap, I want to tell to the second viewController which buttons have been tap, maybe I've to create a variable that represents the status of the button, but I don't know how to do, someone can help me?

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToLast" {

            guard let vc = segue.destination as? FinalClass else { return }

            let guest = segue.destination as! FinalClass

            if let user = sender as? User {


            }
        }
    }
```

where User can be something like

```
 struct User {

    var button1 = Button1 tapped
    var button2 = Button2 tapped
    ecc.

    }
```

Comment: Declare an array in `SecondViewController` and add `tapped buttons` so that when you print the array, you will get tapped buttons only and its state as well.

Comment: @AmirKhan tapped button is for example button1.isHidden = true, how can i declare this in an array? if you can do an example

Comment: What you have been done already? How did you push `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController`? Add some code snippet so that I can add some example of it. :)

Comment: @AmirKhan ok i edited the question, i don't know how to go on from here

Comment: You have already tapped buttons in your `User` model? before push to `SecondViewController` ?

Comment: @AmirKhan yes, so how can i build this user model?

Comment: Seran, go through my answer and let me know if there is something i am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let suppose you have two viewControllers - `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`.

So **First**,

Let Declare two Arrays in `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` something like -

```
var tappedButtonsArray = NSMutableArray() // In 'FirstViewController'
           AND
var previousViewTappedButtonsArray = NSMutableArray() // In 'SecondViewController'
```

And here is my code to add | remove tapped buttons to | from `tappedButtonsArray` in `FirstViewController` -

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) { // Single action for all buttons


    if (tappedButtonsArray.contains(sender)){ 

        tappedButtonsArray.remove(sender) // Remove previous tapped button on unselect
    }
    else{

        tappedButtonsArray.add(sender) // Add tapped button on select
    }


}
```

And **Here is your perform segue method:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToLast" {

        guard let secondViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController else { return }

        secondViewController.previousViewTappedButtonsArray = tappedButtonsArray
    }
}
```

I've done with a simple array concept without any model, so that you can understand the follow. I hope it'll help you to start with.